# What is wrong with the placement of my API key?

Tags: python, api, finance, api-key

When I run my code, I get the error

> TypeError: DataReader() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_key'

Where should I put my API key in my code?

I'm running anaconda3 on Mac OSX

I've tried putting it in a number of places but I get the same error; it either doesn't belong in the place I put it, or it says it hasn't been able to find an API key.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import quandl

osif = ['AAPL','TSLA']

osif_portfolio = pd.DataFrame()

for osif in zip(osif):
    osif_portfolio[osif]= wb.DataReader(osif, data_source='quandl', api_key ="fakekey123456789", start='2018-1-1')['AdjClose']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for DataReader: https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/blob/master/pandas_datareader/data.py#L256 it looks like the keyword argument should be `access_key`?

Comment: Great! If you could mark this answer as accepted to help others in future, that would be great!